# Replace individual character elements of string

Tags: python, string

I need help in how to identify a character from the user input? And how to replace with specific character of my own.

**The Task:**

1. This program prompts the user to enter a DNA sequence (A,T,C,G) and display the reverse complement of that DNA sequence
2. The program should only accept the DNA bases (A,T,C,G) uppercase letter only, **if not**, convert the character to 'x'

My problem is in the second step of the program, in how to replace the letters that are not upper-cased (A,C,G,T) with 'x' character

```
seq= input('Enter a DNA sequence ')

seqcom = {'A':'T','C':'G','T':'A','G':'C'} # dictionary 

letters = list(seq)
letters.reverse ()
dna =''

for base in letters:
    dna += seqcom[base]


print('The reverse complement of \n', seq, '\n', 'is\n', dna)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want: [`dict.get(key[, default])`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get)

```
for base in letters:
    dna += seqcom.get(base, 'x')
```

Comment: Would `dna = [seqcom.get(base, 'x') for base in letters]` be faster ? I know this generates a list, but I just wanted to know how they'd perform.

Comment: @Pavan: Yes, ''.join(seqcom.get(base, 'x') for base in letters)` probably would be, since `join` tends to be faster than repeated concatenation